# List of users who registered in the same month as the logged user

Tags: list, joomla

I need to create a custom module which shows a list of users who registered in the same month as the logged user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start with learning how to [create a joomla module](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module).

Then to get familiar with [joomla database functions](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase).

Once you create the module, you have to get the active user using [current user object](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object).

Next step is to run a query to `#__user_profiles` table to get the active user register date. The query will be like:

```
SELECT `registerDate` FROM `#__user_profiles` WHERE `username` = $user_id
```

And then run a second query to get all users registered the same month as active user:

```
SELECT `username` FROM `#__user_profiles` WHERE MONTH(registerDate) = MONTH($current_user_register_date)
```

Good Luck!